# Is there any tool or batch command that allow me to copy local file in another remote server (different domain)?

Tags: windows

I search for any tool or batch command that allow me to copy file /folder from my local machine in a domain to a location in another remote server in different domain ?

Comment: Is this for Active Directory? Also how are the Domains related, same Tree, same site? What kind of permissions do you have in the remote Domain?

Comment: my local pc is in active directory domain and the server is in another active directory domain and  have admin user of remote server

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write a batch file to map a network drive to the remote server, specifying the domain\username and password, then use xcopy or roboocopy to do the copying.

```
net use Z: \\servername\sharename /user:domain\username password
robocopy C:\source\directory\ Z:\destination\directory /E /Z
```

Something like that should do the trick, as long as you have sufficient permissions to map the drive. If you need to pass through a VPN or some such, it may be a bit harder.